# Decent Packet Tutorials for OBJ-C?

Tags: objective-c, tcp, udp, packets

I want to learn more about sending and receiving packets with Obj C. I want to learn more about packet IDs and types. Any ideas on some easy tutorials apart from the Apple Documentation?
Thanks guys!
Note: I do have basic knowlage of how to send packets. But I need to learn more about types and IDs. At the moment Im failing to make a login with login.minecraft.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Holy layer violation, batman!*

I think what you really want to learn about is HTTP communication under iOS, not TCP/IP packets.   In this day and age, there is no reason to dip down to TCP/UDP unless you are *inventing a new protocol*.   For every protocol that exists with any popularity, there is a library that encapsulates it.

In this case, it looks like [Minecraft is built on HTTP](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/User%3aOxguy3/Minecraft.net_API).  Which is no surprise;  unless your game needs realtime interaction, HTTP is a ubiquitous protocol that routes through anything.

Thus, I'd suggest you start with one of the [HTTP programming guides](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i).